# Объект неуправляемого класса в управляемом классе

Tags: c++-cli

Допустим, у меня есть свой класс и он управляемый.
И я хочу, чтобы в нем были переменные неуправляемого класса.
В данном случае это SYSTEMTIME из winbase.h.
Я так понимаю, что в этом случае надо использовать не переменную, а указатель, а переменную объявлять где-то еще. Вопрос в том, где. Если она статическая, еще наверно можно где-то один раз прописать, а если нет? Если попытаться это делать в конструкторе, то компилятор ругается. То есть нужна функция, создающая переменную. А как эта функция должна выглядеть?
Мой класс:

```
    ref class MyTime

        {
        public:
            static SYSTEMTIME* currDateAndTimePtr;
            SYSTEMTIME* setDateAndTimePtr;
//...
        }
```

В таком случае со статической работает такой вариант (у меня приложение Windows Forms, так что это находится в MainForm_Load()):

```
SYSTEMTIME currDateAndTime;
MyTime^ currentTime = gcnew MyTime();
currentTime->currDateAndTimePtr = &currDateAndTime;
```

И если в конструкторе написать

```
MyTime::MyTime()
{
    GetLocalTime(currDateAndTimePtr); 
}
```

то все работает. А если попытаться сделать так

```
MyTime::MyTime()
{
    GetLocalTime(currDateAndTimePtr); 
    SYSTEMTIME setDateAndTime;
    setDateAndTimePtr = &setDateAndTime;
}
```

то уже нет.
Как вообще следует поступать в такой ситуации?

Обновление вопроса:
вопрос строчкой выше остается в силе, то есть мне все еще интересен порядок действий при пересечении управляемых и неуправляемых типов.
Но ошибка компилятора вызывалась строчкой GetLocalTime(currDateAndTimePtr); 
Если заменить ее на

```
SYSTEMTIME tempTime;
GetLocalTime(&tempTime);
currDateAndTimePtr = &tempTime;
```

То ошибки не появляется. Тоже вопрос, в чем тут дело?

Comment: Всё, вопрос закрыт